# Copy files from one remote server to another using an SSH key with ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to copy a file that is stored on SERVER-A. This file needs to be copied over to SERVER-B.

I currently use this....**but it is taking so long, and does not work(?)**

Is there a better workaround?

Key Facts:

a) I need an SSH key to copy. It is called **my-key** which I pass into the shell command

b) The file on SERVER-A is located in: **/etc/conf/myConf.xml**

c) The file needs to be copied to SERVER-B in default location: **/home/ubuntu/conf_dir/**

d) The ansible script is run from server-b box.

```
- name:
    "copy file from server-a to server-b"
  shell: scp -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ./my-key ubuntu@10.33.5.44:/etc/conf/myConf.xml /home/ubuntu/conf_dir/
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  become_user: ubuntu
```

Comment: `slurp` the file from *A* back to your controller node and `copy` it to *B* wouldn't be an option?

Answer (score 1):

just use the ansible copy module, this whole shell voodoo is  just prone to errors..

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html

you can set a custom ssh key for this particular task. note that this will only change the ssh private key file for the currently running host.

```
- set_fact: ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/path/to/keyfile
```

Comment: How do you use SSH key with copy module?

Comment: not sure what makes it necessary to use an additional ssh key , but  ifyou insist in doing this , you can set a key file on playbook level with host vars. vars:
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{ key1 }}"

Comment: Hmm, not sure I quite follow... can you please give an example using my context please? :)